# Error on Visual Studio 2012 Startup - The file could not be loaded. An attempt to repair this condition failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've been searching for hours but i cant find a solution for this, also i cant find the logs of VS2012.

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: The error message suggests reinstalling, did you try that?

Comment: reinstalling is too much, i just created a new account in windows and then deleted the old one.

Comment: connect.microsoft.com is slow but working way to report bug to Microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by Reapplying the Update 3 of VS2012

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error yesterday, after update of VS. I didn't found solution, so I just reinstalled VS 2012.

Comment: Maybe reinstalling is the solution...

Comment: Reinstalling is always the last solution, but for OP information about updating VS and then collapse could be helpful to find solution. I didn't have enough time yesterday to find it..